# Unknown DC power pin

Tags: power-supply

I'm purchasing this power module:
[image]

I don't know what is the NC pin.

Any idea?

Comment: No connection, or not connected. Honestly if you cant get info on a particular pin of a product, you shouldn't buy it.

Comment: Remotely related - in a context of switches/relays "NC" might mean "normally closed".

Answer (score 5):

NC means "no connection" usually. Probably it's a pin that is there to provide mechanical support.

Since this is a high voltage (mains + transients) module I would strongly suggest consulting the [datasheet](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1509/1638/files/220V_zu_5V_Mini_Netzteil_Datenblatt_AZ-Delivery_Vertriebs_GmbH_rev1_c86b6a99-558d-4e8e-9644-354f466e0795.pdf?v=1620718279) to ensure that any spacing requirements are being met on the pad for the NC pin.

Note: Since the supplier's datasheet offers no particular help in this regard, leave spacing with the assumption it has mains voltage on it. They do offer this helpful warning

[image]